# jqGrid get dropdown selected Text value in Save Mode

Tags: jqgrid

I have a dropdown in jqGrid. In Edit mode we can get dropdown selected text value using 
$("#"+gridId+"_dicountType option:selected").text(); but in save mode How we can get  dropdown selected Text value.

Thanks a lot,
prince

Comment: Could you define what you mean under "Save Mode"? Could you include JavaScript code which shows how jqGrid will be created? At least the definition of `dicountType` column in `colModel` could be importank to know.

Comment: Hi Oleg, If we click on grid row dropdown will appear that is edit mode. If we click another row the previous row is saved now and instead of dropdown selected text will appear that is Save Mode.

Comment: I can repeat that **there are no "Save Mode"**. It's just the standard grid which you use. There are tree editing mode which supports jqGrid with different implementation options. The modified data can be saved either locally only (if you use `editurl: "clientArray"`) or saved both locally and on the server. After saving the data in the cell are just text (if you don't use formatters). So to get the data you can use `jQuery('#list').jqGrid ('getCell', rowId, 'columnName')` (see the answer of Ajo Koshy). If you don't get the cell value then you use **wrong parameters of `getCell`**

Comment: Hi Oleg, let's use one of your  demo http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DependendSelects2.htm  I am trying to get Country Col text using this jQuery("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam","data");
jQuery("#list").jqGrid ('getCell', 1, 'Country'); But its showing "1" or some other number but not Country name.

Comment: It's absolutely correct because the column use `formatter: 'select'`. If you examine input data of the grid you will see that `mydata` contains the value from options of select and not the text.

Comment: I think u misunderstood my question. This is what i asked in my question How we can get dropdown selected Text value (e.g US) when its just a standard grid.

Comment: I think that you should post new question and describe more clear and detailed your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Once a row in `jqGrid` is saved the cell reverts to **text** format rather than **dropdown** format. So all you have to do is use the `rowId` to get the data from the cell.
**EDIT:**

```
var dataFromRow = jQuery('#list').jqGrid ('getRowData', rowId);
var dataFromCellByColumnIndex = jQuery('#list').jqGrid ('getCell', rowId, 7);
var dataFromCellByColumnName = jQuery('#list').jqGrid ('getCell', rowId, 'column_index');
```

Comment: It will work only when row in edit mode otherwise it will give output as undefined.

Comment: you can use `$("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','data');` to get  data from the grid and iterate over it

Comment: I already tried this also but its showing key value not Text value.